# Why does the following php file does not work?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The following is the log.php file that is running on google app engine locally (on localhost).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $filename = "log.txt";
    file_put_contents($filename, $name, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
```

I am calling the above file using the following jquery call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: './php/log.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {name: name},
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

I believe the ajax is working as I get a log on console which is just the entire php code. But  the php is not writing anything into the log.txt file. Can anyone please help?

Comment: There aren't any. As I have already said, the console output is just the whole php code.

Comment: you should specify the used JSframework (jQuery?) and think about your  prblem. i can not see any output to log n console and i personally can not understand the problem at all.

Answer (score 5):

As you get in the AJAX response the entire PHP code then you most probably don't have the App Engine or PHP configured properly.

Since you get the PHP code as plain text, then the server isn't configured to run it as code and does not recognize it as such.

Check that.